# 1 hour is added to .NET DateTime object in HTTP request

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

I'm doing a HTTP transport using POST and one of the fields in the XML I'm sending is DateTime.

Before the XML is sent I can see that its value is:

> 2014-03-21T00:00:00

, but when the interface I'm sending to receives it, it has been changed to:

> 2014-03-21T01:00:00

How can I create the DateTime object so it keeps it original value all the way?

At the moment I'm creating it like this:

```
DateTime today = DateTime.Today;
```

Comment: Have you checked for timezone differences between sending and receiving ends?  For ease, send and receive in UTC to avoid such drifts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> DateTime.UtcNow.Date

You likely are in the UK - 1 hour difference to UTC - and there is a timezone conversion happening.

Comment: I'm guessing Western Europe, actually - the UK hasn't moved into summer time yet.

Comment: Yes, I'm in Norway. Will try the UtcNow.

Comment: Well, let's make it more generic: Every time you get funny time conversions, check timezones on both sides and what is transferred. Normally that is a discrepancy on arrangement (i.e. one side sends UTC, other one thinks it is local time).